Grub won't dual boot Windows 10
Edit: Pretty sure the problem was I destroyed the original EFI partition with my sequence of OS installs. Fixed the problem by reinstalling Windows then Linux.
New to linux, tried to dual boot, and installed Debian 12 on one of my SSD's.
I've tried for a day and have not been able to get Grub to load Windows 10, and am now stuck in Debian.
Would appreciate any help; I am losing my sanity trying to get my current OS back.
I've tried the following (secure boot, fast boot etc. are all disabled in BIOS):
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 3C26-6A4C
    chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}    

Grub responded with "EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi not found"
Going into /boot/efi/EFI there is only "debian" and no "Microsoft". I believe there should be the Microsoft bootloader there, but does not exist?
menuentry "Windows 10" --class windows --class os {
   insmod ntfs
   search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid $your_uuid_here$
   ntldr /bootmgr
}

"ntldr command not found"
My attempts mostly followed https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425637/how-can-i-add-windows-11-to-grub-menu and https://askubuntu.com/questions/661947/add-windows-10-to-grub-os-list/977251#977251
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: Sabrent SB-ROCKET-NVMe4-2TB             
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5F288D54-70BA-40A5-9A5C-EFCC254BC586

Device         Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1  2048      34815      32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme1n1p2 34816 3907028991 3906994176  1.8T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SNV2S1000G                     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1C866584-28D1-4523-807E-FFCD57625770

Device              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048    1050623    1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1050624 1951522815 1950472192 930.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 1951522816 1953523711    2000896   977M Linux swap

# blkid /dev/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="9455-99E4" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="02868e84-e1df-4b0f-ab1b-a1b4806e295a

Again, would greatly appreciate any help.

It seems you may have let the Debian installer format the EFI System partition (/dev/nvme0n1p1), destroying the bootloader of Windows that used to be there. You will have to use Windows recovery tools to fix that first. Since the current "UUID" of the vfat filesystem on nvme0n1p1 is 9455-99E4 and there doesn't seem to be any other vfat filesystems around, where did you get 3C26-6A4C from?

If you have the Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting set, it leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

It doesn't seem like you have any Windows installation at all / anymore (assuming the 2TB Sabrent drive is a "data drive" and hence irrelevant; otherwise you have wrongly converted its partition table to GPT).
